# Explanation of yellow/pinkish sky?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere

Last night the sky suddenly went yellow/pinkish colour. It looked like someone placed a transparent yellow/red plastic over our windows. I went outside and everything looked a pink/yellow colour, people where I live were confused. We thought it was a storm but there was no rain or anything after it. It was so weird, everything looked like it was tinted. It was almost like it looked iridescent or something?

What could it be? Could someone explain?

Comment: What do you mean by "iricandesent"? There are two words: incandescent and iridescent, with slightly similar meaning but still different.

Comment: Can you provide more detail? Before/during/shortly after/long after sunset? Location? Pictures?

Comment: I know what you mean, I can't describe it any better than you have. I don't have any pictures, but I've seen it here in Northern Indiana.

Comment: Could you provide more information? How long did it last? Did it extend over the entire sky? What were the atmospheric conditions that day?

Comment: If you live somewhere near the wild fires, that might be a possible explanation.   The soot and pollution from the fire would add color, especially around sunset when the sun has more atmosphere to pass through.     An aurora could be another explanation but my guess would be the wild fires over California, if you live not too far east of there.

Comment: Closing this as unclear due to lack of details.  If you come back, please add details as requested and you can flag it to be re-opened.